# Eclipse project selection empty

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to integrate Google play services into my app. I get to this one instruction which tells me to right click the project, select properties, select the android tab and then hit add to add the required things but when I click add the project selection box is empty. Does anyone know what is going on here and how to fix it?

Thanks